# Possible to declare a method in super class that returns an object of type subclass?

Tags: java, generics, type-safety

I have a class called Calculator, which is extended by many other classes. It has a method called intern() which reads as follows:

```
   public DailyValueCalculator intern() {
    if (TimeSeriesIterator.containsMatchingCalculator(this)) {
        TimeSeriesIterator.removeCalculator(this);
        return TimeSeriesIterator.getMatchingCalculator(this);
    } else {
        return this;
    }
}
```

If I have, say, a BetaCalculator called bc, I'd like to be able to intern it by saying

```
bc = bc.intern();
```

Currently though I have to say

```
bc = (BetaCalculator) bc.intern();
```

Is there any way to make it so that the intern() method would always have a return type of the type on which it was called? And if there isn't a way to do this, is there a reason why it's not possible?

Possible solutions I'm aware of though am unsatisfied with:

1. Rewriting the intern() method in every calculator I write
2. Passing the intern() method a Class and having it return a T (e.g.

   <T extends DailyValueCalculator> T intern(Class<T> returnType){...}
3. Giving DailyValueCalculator a Type <T> (i.e. making it DailyValueCalculator<T>) that all subclasses would be required to specify where T is equal to the type of the subclass and then having intern() return a T.

Comment: Check the Factory pattern and ist variants...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it if you type your super-class with itself. Here is an example:

```
public abstract class SuperClass<S extends SuperClass<S>> {

    public S intern() {
        return (S) this;
    }

    public static class SubClass extends SuperClass<SubClass> {

        private void methodOnlyInSubClass() {
            System.out.println("subclass method");
        }

        public void myMethod() {
            SubClass sub = intern();
            sub.methodOnlyInSubClass();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Right, this was what I had in mind above as solution 3) -- I'd prefer not to do this because this Calculator object is a part of an API and our clients, who for the most part will have a limited knowledge of java, might be confused if when creating Calculators they're required to type the class with itself. Might be the best way to go though regardless

Comment: @Accipheran As an alternative, you could write a static method like this `public static <S> S intern(S something)` But it is static.

Answer (score -1):

No there's no way to do this. Think about it: I know you know that the intern method is just going to return back the same class, but how could the compiler?